# Getting from Skövde to Jönköping?

Tags: public-transport, sweden, jonkoping

What's the best (cheapest and fastest) opportunity to get from Skövde to Jönköping by public transport during a weekend?

Skövde to Jönköping on Friday evening and back on Sunday evening.

Comment: It might be worth tagging this with the country/countries?

Comment: [ResRobot](http://reseplanerare.resrobot.se/bin/query.exe/en?L=vs_resrobot) looks a good bet for finding the routes and timings, but it doesn't do prices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just take a train. According to [SJ's very functional site](http://www.sj.se/start/startpage/index.form?l=en), there are about hourly departures between the cities, with the last one from Skövde C on Friday at 20:54. For return trip, last train leaves Jönköping C at 21:59 on Sunday.

2nd class ticket costs either 136 or 154 SEK (depending on if it's operated by [Västtrafik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A4sttrafik) or SJ). There are plenty of direct trains, but with some you'd have to change at Falköping. Travel time by train is between 1:05 and 1:14.

[There are buses too](http://www.swebus.se/Express/Sokresultat/?from=154&fromtype=BusStop&to=19&totype=City&away=2011-10-28&home=2011-10-30&Adult=1&Child=0&Youth=0&Student=0&Pensioner=0#bookingSearchResultsAway): travel time 1:30; prices from 129 SEK. Last departure from Skövde resecentrum (= central train/bus station) on Fri at 18:55, and from Jönköping on Sun at 21:25.

Comment: Oh, prices quoted are one-way. I didn't check if buying a two-way ticket gets you a discount.

Comment: it doesn't but the price may vary depending on many things. (At least when it comes to SJ. Last time I booked a trip a first class ticket was cheaper than a second class one....) If under 25 you may get a cheap last minute ticket.

Answer (score 6):

There are two options - bus and train - that both cost about 200-300 SEK depending on when you book. For the upcoming weekend the bus price is 258 SEK. Check out [swebus.se](http://www.swebus.se) for details. With train you end up at 272 SEK. Check out [sj.se](http://www.sj.se) for details. The train at 1''05 is 25 minutes faster than the bus.